# Facebook Lint not picking up OG tags

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph, lint

I'm using the proper Facebook Open Graph meta tags, but Facebook is not picking them up when I try to share the page. This is a Wordpress site and I have the meta tags generated based on information from the post. For example, on this page: http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/2012/03/16/danger-gal-friday-dejah-thoris

It outputs the following HTML:

`<meta property="og:title" content="Danger Gal Friday: Dejah Thoris" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/2012/03/16/danger-gal-friday-dejah-thoris/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/dejah_thoris-221x300.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>This week&#8217;s Danger Gal Friday profiles Dejah Thoris as portrayed by classically-trained Lynn Collins in Disney&#8217;s new movie &#8220;John Carter.&#8221; The movie doesn&#8217;t stop with showing us only one great female character, though. Fulfilling the usual sidekick-type role we have Sola, an individualist barely surviving in a hive-type society. </p>
" />`

I thought maybe the `<p>` tags in the description might be causing the problem, but when I remove that it still doesn't work. The Linter is scraping information from my homepage instead of the single post page (URL above). Why is it doing this and how can I fix it so that it scrapes information from the proper page?

Comment: Have you noticed that the bottom of your pages appear to have been hacked to display spam? `<a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/112/'>best place to buy viagra online</a><a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/56/'>tramadol 200mg</a><a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/94/'>buy xanax bars no prescription</a><a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/92/'>cialis ordering</a><a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/24/'>buying viagra uk</a></body>`

Comment: I don't see that when I look at either the URL in my question or the homepage. How were you able to see that?

Comment: I did `curl http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/2012/03/16/danger-gal-friday-dejah-thoris` in my command line. It may be hidden from logged-in users to prevent you from seeing it. Your WordPress install has been hacked.

Comment: The linter is reporting your canonical url as your home page and has a response code of 206 (partial response). Although you're providing the canonical url and the og:url in your meta, something is forcing it back to the home page (although I'm not sure what). If your wordpress install has in fact been hacked, it could be related. Also, you should be stripping the html from your tags as well (regardless of whether or not that's the problem in this scenario).

Answer (score 0):

This shows up with curl in the footer:

```
<a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/94/'>buy xanax bars no prescription</a>
<a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/56/'>tramadol 200mg</a>
<a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/92/'>cialis ordering</a>
<a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/112/'>best place to buy viagra online</a><a href='http://www.lisapaitzspindler.com/blog/page/24/'>buying viagra uk</a></body>
```

Even though sucuri shows the site is clean: http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/lisapaitzspindler.com

Dreamhost is particularly bad for hacks. You need to completely clean your hosting account and consider changing hosts, too.

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and tell your host. Change all passswords. Scan your own PC.